# Correct use of Singleton Pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, synchronization, singleton

I am trying to implement an example of the singleton pattern. One of our questions is to run two threads each calling getInstance() and to verify only one instance of the Singleton object was created.

Here is my Singleton code;

```
public class OurSingleton {

    static OurSingleton ourSingleton;
    static int instanceCounter;

    private OurSingleton(){
        instanceCounter++;
    }

    public static synchronized OurSingleton GetSingletonInstance(){

        if( ourSingleton == null){

            ourSingleton = new OurSingleton();

        }
        return ourSingleton;    
    }

    public static int getCounter() {

        return instanceCounter;

    }
}
```

And my main;

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OurSingleton mySingleton = null;

        Thread one = new Thread(new GetSingletonInstance(mySingleton));
        Thread two = new Thread(new GetSingletonInstance(mySingleton));

        one.start();
        two.start();


        System.out.println("Main: " + mySingleton.getCounter());
    }   
}

class GetSingletonInstance implements Runnable {

    int count = 0;
    OurSingleton singleton;

    public GetSingletonInstance(OurSingleton ourSingleton){
        singleton = ourSingleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (count < 5000000) {
                singleton.getSingletonInstance();
                count++;    
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Thread: " + singleton.getCounter());

    }       
}
```

When I run this code I get the following output;

> Main: 0 Thread: 1 Thread: 1

Can somebody explain the reason for this output? I thought only a single instance of Singleton existed across the board. Does this mean another object is being created in the threads ?? Any advice is appreciated !

Comment: First of all, please start all class names in Java w/ a capital letter. You just made me think that Java had first class functions. I got all excited then realized that your code was not idiomatic. :(

Comment: `Thread one = new Thread(new getSingletonInstance(mySingleton));` -- What's the second `new` doing there? Ah, that's a class! Strange.

Comment: The class name is like dropping toothpicks in a haystack where you are trying to find a needle. Just to make it more confusing for beginners like me.

Comment: This `getInstanceCounter++;` is in the constructor, that should only be called once? I think you want that piece of code in your `getSingletonInstance()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one `OurSingleton` instance, but the class `getSingletonInstance` (USE PROPER CAPS!) is not a singleton itself. And it is the one where you put the counter.

Comment: Didn't even notice the class name was lower case, thanks! When I run the code, sometimes the output is Main: 1, Thread: 1, Thread: 1. Do you know why ??

Comment: The order of execution of the threads cannot be determined in advance. Sometimes the main thread will end before the others have instantiated the singleton, sometimes the main thread will sleep, giving time for another thread to instantiate the singleton. Once the singleton is instantiated, all the values printed in all the threads are `1`.

Answer (score 8):

You should avoid synchronizing the `getInstance` method (because it's just an unnecessary overhead just to get the instance once it has been initialized). Following is the recommended way for lazy-initializing singleton:

```
public class OurSingleton {

    private OurSingleton() { }

    public static OurSingleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static OurSingleton instance = new OurSingleton();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> thought only a single instance of Singleton existed across the board.
>   Does this mean another object is being created in the threads ??

Only one instance of singleton exists in the JVM; each of your threads displays the fact that there is only one instance.

The easiest and safest way to implement the Singleton Pattern in Java is by using enums:

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    public void doStuffHere() {
        //...
    }
}

public class ClientClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        MySingleton mySingleton = MySingleton.INSTANCE;
        mySingleton.doStuff();
    }
}
```

You have only one instance of MySingleton and it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

You have created 2 instances of thread from the same class. Each one prints number of instances of your singleton object. The number is 1 that means that you indeed created only one instance, so that your singleton is implemented correctly. 
You printed this twice because you created 2 threads.

If you want to avoid confusing move line `System.out.println(...)` to your main method.

Answer (score 2):

I would explain this so:

When you loaded the class `OurSingleton`, the static counter `getInstanceCounter` is initialized to zero.Then how many ever times you get a new instance of the class, the counter is always 1, indicating that you have indeed a singleton.

I would suggest making the following changes

1. Make the static variables in Singleton private: `ourSingleton`, `getInstanceCounter`
2. Remove the synchronized keyword on the method, since its an unnecessary overhead

Comment: Removing synchronized will cause the program to occasionally output Thread: 2, Thread: 2

Comment: `synchronized` is required or you can create two `OurSingleton`s. (Not that I would recommend this aproach anyway, I side with the use `enum` for singleton crowd). This is because the first thread can pass the null check, then second thread takes over, also passes null check and creates object, then first thread also creates object when control is returned to it.

Comment: That's true, which is why removing simply removing synchronized isn't a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Look at the other answer for how to do this better, for your question why are you getting this output

```
Main: 0 
Thread: 1
Thread: 1
```

with the code

```
static int getInstanceCounter;
```

you are setting declaring and setting an static variable to zero. So before any instance of OurSingleton has been created getInstanceCounter has a value of zero. 
When you call

```
System.out.println("Main: " + mySingleton.getCounter());
```

No instance of OurSignleton has been created so mySignleton.getCounter() is still zero.

Running of either or both threads will cause one instance of OurSingleton to be created and getInstanceCounter will be one.

Your singleton is working. Though better ways have been mentioned in other answers.

---

As an aside a few things about your code which may seem nit picky but will help other people read your code.

- Please make variable private

  static int getInstanceCounter; =>
  private static int getInstanceCounter;
- Variables should not be named with get

  private static int getInstanceCounter; =>
  private static int instanceCounter;
- Don't refer to static methods on an instance of a class

  mySingleton.getCounter() =>
  OurSingleton.getCount()
- This also means that the variable mySingleton which is never assigned a value should never be referenced and should be deleted.

  public GetSingletonInstance(OurSingleton ourSingleton){
      singleton = ourSingleton;
  }
  =>
  public GetSingletonInstance(){
      singleton = OurSingleton.getInstance();
  }

Answer (score 0):

The access to `OurSingleton.getInstanceCounter` (static member) via  `OurSingleton.getCounter ()` (static member function) is not synchronized. That is the only thing that matters. The remainder of your program is simply complicating things. Note that in `main` you are via `mySingleton.getCounter ()` calling a static function on a `null` pointer! `mySingleton` never has another value than `null`.

You should use `enum` to implement the singleton pattern, or at least use only one static variable, namely the one holding the singleton object.

Comment: The value of `mySingleton` is irrelevant, `null` or otherwise, since the compiled code doesn't use it.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's syntactically correct and does not crash, but I think it might indicate a "logical bug" (i.e. the author most likely had something different in mind when he wrote the code). Definitely the non-synchronization is due to the call of `getCounter` in `main`.

Comment: Funny thing is, the observed behavior is completely correct, it doesn't show any artifacts of incorrect synchronization. There is nothing in the program logic forcing the counter to 1 in `main`.

Comment: Well, but which thread first calls `getCounter` is random. You can as well get the output Main: 1, Thread: 1, Thread: 1.

Comment: Exactly. Both behaviors are legal.